# Is it possible to filter certain push notifications on Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I am using OneSignal for push notification. I want to filter some push notification and hide from user according to condition.

There are two Login in my app and the user can login to both at the same time. I have different table for holding user data including OneSignal User Id. I am able to send notification with additional data and navigate to screen according to this data like `` "type`:"a" `` or `"type:"b` .

The user can signout offline so i am using workmanager to delete OneSignal User Id from database and prevent to send notification.

My problem is when the user signout one of the two login while offline, OneSignal User Id is not deleted until the user is online. In this period of time, my server can send notification to OneSignal User Id that will be deleted. So when the user is online, also receives these notifications.

I tried `OneSignal.shared.setSubscription(false)` but this function prevents to receive all notification but i want to receive "type b" notification only.

Is there any handler for to do like below? Or Do you have any suggestion for to do this?

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
    var additionalData = openedResult.notification.payload.additionalData;
    if(additionalData["type"] == "a" && !isTypeALogin){
         //Dont Show This Notification
    }
});
```

**Update:**
OneSignal Flutter SDK 3 Beta have  `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler` for to do that. So i decided to change online signout only. [Related github issue](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/393)

Answer (score 0):

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
  var additionalData = openedResult.notification.payload.additionalData;
  if(additionalData["type"] == "a" && !isTypeALogin){
     //Dont Show This Notification
     notification.complete(null);
    }
});
```